# Crystal Reports 2008: Subreport is affecting my "sum" formulas in the main report?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008, subreport

This issue is slowly driving me mad. My report structure is thus:

```
Group 1 - Department
    Group 2 - Secondary Department
       Group 3 - Author
            Group 4 - Task
```

At the top level (Department) I want to show the length of all tasks. This is collected from a database and is in seconds. An example column:

```
5
7
14
12
23
8
8
```

I expect this to be 77. When the user drills down to the 4th level, Task, they can click a link that takes them to a subreport.

This subreport is a task audit (i.e, information on each time the task was interacted with (such as opening, closing, saving etc.) typically, there might be 3 or 4 rows in the audit).

The subreport is linked to the main report via the GUID of the task. Ergo, when the user clicks the link on level 4, they see an audit for that task.

With no subreport, it works as expected and the total length is set to 77 seconds. However, with the subreport, the number is much higher, for example, 245 seconds. The number is always the actual length of time * the number of times the task appears in the audit (if there are 4 rows in the audit, the length is 4 times higher than it should be)

Is there ANY way I can make this link 'one-way'? I do not want my subreport to be affecting my actual main report, I just want it to be a link to show another report, filtered by the task's ID.

Failing this, is there any other way to properly calculate the sum of the data in this column whilst ensuring it ignores the subreport? The subreport uses a different table and does not have the same column.

Thanks

Comment: didn't get exactly..... sub report linking is only one way... correct? are you passing any data from sub report to main report?

Comment: Nope, i am passing an id to the subreport to filter data. I am not intentionally sending back data the other way, as far as i know!

Comment: I'm confident I can help but need a bit more info.  In Group1, you want to display a COUNT of tasks in Group4, and this is a SUM field you are using?